# SQL SERVER XML query returns nothing

Tags: sql-server

Every or some ssrs reports have following tags:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"
xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily"
MustUnderstand="df"
```

This query doesn't return any data unless I remove the attributes specified above. In the given xml, attributes can't be removed.

```
declare @content xml =
'<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily" MustUnderstand="df">
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DS">
      <Query>
        <CommandText>rep.my_proc</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>'

  select 
      'DB growth' as ReportName, 
      CommandText = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
  from  @content.nodes('Report/DataSets/DataSet') r (x)
```

Is there any error in that query?

Comment: Add `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' )` before the `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

```
declare @content xml =
'<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"     xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily" MustUnderstand="df">
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DS">
      <Query>
        <CommandText>rep.my_proc</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition')
select 
    'DB growth' as ReportName, 
    CommandText = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
from @content.nodes('Report/DataSets/DataSet') r (x)
```